# Was Puella Magi Oriko Magica Another Story ever translated into english? If not, are there plans to translate it?

Tags: manga-production, madoka-magica

I looked on amazon.com and on the internet and I couldn't find any references to there being an english version. I would really like to read so if anyone had any information on this it would be great if they could share it.

Answer (score 5):

*Puella Magi Oriko Magica* is licensed in the US by Yen Press. The two volumes were released on [July and October 2013](http://www.yenpress.com/puella-magi-oriko-magica/). The continuation chapters: "Noisy Citrine," "Symmetry Diamond," and "The Last Agate" are collected in *Mahou Shoujo Oriko Magica: Betsu Hen (Another Story)*, and the newest continuation, "Sadness Prayer" have not yet been licensed.

Additionally, *Puella Magi Madoka Magica: The Different Story* has been [licensed](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2013-08-23/yen-press-adds-sword-art-online-accel-world-light-novels-more-madoka-magica-manga) by [Yen Press](http://www.yenpress.com/madoka-magica-different-story/). Three volumes are expected to be released March, June, and October 2014.